# Why isn't my ionic modal opening on an android 4.4 device?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework, angular-ui

I am using ionic framework with a android device (with cordova, of course). There's a modal I'm using for settings and stuff, it opens well on desktop browser with

```
`inic serve`
```

However, after build this, either with

`cordova build android` or `ionic build android`

it won't open again, not only is it in an real android device, but also in the desktop browser.

Here's the code:

for the html view:

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Settings</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="hideModal()">Done</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <form name="settingsForm" novalidate>
            <ion-item class="item-input">
                <label class="input-label">IP Address</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.ipAddress" name="ipAddr" required />
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="item-input">
                <label class="input-label">Port Number</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.portNum" name="portNum" required />
            </ion-item>
            <a class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="vm.startCommand()" 
                ng-disabled="settingsForm.ipAddr.$invalid || settingsForm.portNum.$invalid && !vm.isListening">{{vm.btnString}}</a>
        </form>
        <br />
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-divider">Messages from socket ws://{{vm.ipAddress}}:{{vm.portNum}} -></ion-item>
            <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="msg in vm.msgs">{{msg}}</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

for the controller:

```
/// <reference path="../_reference.ts" />

module app.settings {
    interface IModelScope extends angular.IScope {
        model: Ionic.IModal;

        showModal(): void;
        hideModal(): void;
    }

    interface ISettingsCtrl {
        ipAddress: string;
        portNum: number;
        msgs: string[];
        btnString: string;

        startCommand(): void;
    }

    class SettingsCtrl implements ISettingsCtrl {
        ipAddress: string;
        portNum: number;
        msgs: string[] = [];
        btnString: string = 'Start';
        private _gotDirective: boolean;

        private _isListening: boolean = false;

        static $inject = ['$scope', 'SocketSvc', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicModal', '$ionicLoading'];
        constructor(private _scope: IModelScope,
            private _socketSvc: app.service.ISocketSvc,
            private _ionicPopup: Ionic.IPopup,
            private _ionicModel: Ionic.IModal,
            private _ionicLoading: Ionic.ILoading) {
            _ionicModel.fromTemplateUrl('../../settings/settings.html', {
                scope: _scope,
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            }).then(m => {
                _scope.model = m;
            });

            _scope.showModal = () => {
                _scope.model.show();
            }

            _scope.hideModal = () => {
                _scope.model.hide();
            }
        }

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('SettingsCtrl', SettingsCtrl);
}
```

yes, i'm using typescript

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by *won't open again*? Do you see any error? Have you tried to build with the *verbose* flag (`cordova -d build android`)?

Comment: @GuillemVicens I found the answer, see the answer below. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad you found it. Don't forget to accept your own answer so others can see quickly your questions had a solution. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GuillemVicens well, it turns out the ionic framework starter gives you a nice place to start but not cordova-friendly enough. In the ionic project, I put my settings.html under the

`/www/settings/settings.html`

and settings.ctrl.ts

`/www/scripts/settings/settings.ctrl.ts`

So I use the

```
_ionicModel.fromTemplateUrl('../../settings/settings.html', {
    scope: _scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}
```

to try to specify the modal's template. However in cordova, it package all the

`www`

into the

`assets/www`

witch should be fine because it still got all this hierarchy (which turns out not).

All the scripts turns to run **just** under the

`/assets/www`

directory, so if you switch your

`../../settings/settings.html` into `./settings/settings.html`

it'll work just fine.

**For who don't have much time, the scripts run in browser just under it's own directory, but in android, it run under the `/www/` directory, so make sure you use the relative addressing right.**